Change shell background color with start of virtual environment
Currently I have a few environments for different projects. I would like to have the terminal background color change at the start of each environment. For instance, if I have an environment named chemistry_env and I type:
micomamba activate chemistry_env

I would like the background color to change from default white to something else for each environment and then when I deactivate have the color change back to white again. For clarity I'm not wanting to change the prompt color but the actual background window. Is this doable? Using zsh and micromamba.
I'm relatively new to virtual environments and so far in my SO searches I have not seen this.

I'm on WSL so can't test this directly (I'm assuming you're on macos?) - does running export PS1="" && printf '\e[48;5;196m' && clear make your screen bright red? If it does then you should be able to write a script that sets PS1 to something sensible that doesn't involve colors (otherwise it overwites the ANSII codes in ^^), changes the background color then calls micomamba
